# Deploying PHP project to different directories using GIT

Tags: php, git, yii

My document root as follows (I'm using virtualmin)

```
/home/myvps/domains/example.com/public_html
```

I'm only keep `index.php`, `.htacess` and few asset files there. I want to keep other files in following directory

```
/home/myvps/domains/example.com/app
```

Specifically, I am using Yii and the user-content-directory-structure given at:

- https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced#user-content-directory-structure

I want to deploy my project using GIT to production server. What I'm currently doing is keeping a bare repo in `/home/myvps.com/domains/example.com/app.git` and employed a `post-receive hook` which contains following lines

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/myvps/domains/example.com/app  git checkout -f
```

Then I can push to server directly.

But, since it doesn't touch the public_html directory, I have to modify and upload the files from /app/web manually every time if these files required any modifications.

What is the best way to use GIT in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [info you gave in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30486988#30486988), I suggest to symlink either the relevant files or the entire public folder to Yii's app/web folder. That way, you can keep the changes under version control and don't need to manually change them after a deploy.